# DispatchKeyEvent not firing on my View

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, keyboard, xamarin.android

I need to intercept physical key events in a CustomView so I wrote this:

```
   public class CustomView : View
   {
        public override bool DispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e)
        {
            return base.DispatchKeyEvent(e);
        }
    }
```

I don't know why the `DispatchKeyEvent` **is never called** when I press any key.

How can I make it work?

NOTE: It seems that overriding the same method in an Activity, it works, but I need to do it in my **CustomView**.

Comment: It seems that the key event was been handled by the Activity so it  cant been passes to the view.

Comment: Your Customview must get focused and then the KeyEvent can pass to  CustomView from your Activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once your `customView` is `Focused` and `FocusableInTouchMode = true`, you can catch the `KeyEvent`. From the `DispatchEvent` source code, we can see this :

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {

    if ((mPrivateFlags & (PFLAG_FOCUSED | PFLAG_HAS_BOUNDS))
            == (PFLAG_FOCUSED | PFLAG_HAS_BOUNDS)) {
        // If this ViewGroup is focused and its size has been set(has border),pass the KeyEvent to the view

        if (super.dispatchKeyEvent(event)) {
            return true;
        }
    } else if (mFocused != null && (mFocused.mPrivateFlags & PFLAG_HAS_BOUNDS)
            == PFLAG_HAS_BOUNDS) {
        //If this ViewGroup has a focused child,and the child has a size
        if (mFocused.dispatchKeyEvent(event)) { 
            return true; 
           // We can see that only the child is focused it can be catch the key event
        }
    }

    if (mInputEventConsistencyVerifier != null) {
        mInputEventConsistencyVerifier.onUnhandledEvent(event, 1);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Therefore, the `customView` must been focused to can catch `KeyEvent`,

**I solve this problem, Add this code to your `customView`** :

```
public GameView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) : base(context, attrs, defStyle)
{
     //Set whether this view can receive the focus
     this.Focusable = true;

    //When a view is focusable, it may not want to take focus when in touch mode.
    //For example, a button would like focus when the user is navigating via a D-pad
    //so that the user can click on it, but once the user starts touching the screen,
    //the button shouldn't take focus
     this.FocusableInTouchMode = true;
}

//Returns whether this View is able to take focus
public override bool IsFocused => true;
```

Comment: OK! It works! and now I have the Key Code, but how do I get the correct keyboard letter I've pressed? it turn out that pressing the Spanish key "ñ" I'm getting "Keycode.AltLeft". Is there a way to get the actual key? I mean, taking care about the Key Map?

Comment: I have created this separate question to explain it better: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44552029/getting-proper-text-input-from-physical-keyboard-in-android

Comment: you also need to request focus when view active