# Getting proper text input from physical keyboard in Android

Tags: android, keyboard, internationalization, android-input-method

I have a `View` that overrides the `OnKeyDown` event. I can get the Key Code and the KeyEvent, but it seems that I'm missing something.

Let me explain. For non-US keyboard layouts, the Key Code I'm getting is wrong. For example, when I press the ñ key in my **Spanish keyboard**, I expect to receive a "ñ" letter, but instead I get a `Keycode.AltLeft` as Key Code.

How do I get the real letter?

Another problematic case is with accentuated characters: When I press the ´ key and the o key, I shouldn't receive two events, but only one with the letter ó.

Comment: "I expect to receive a "ñ" letter -- there is no `KEYCODE_` value for all characters in all languages. When you [call `getUnicodeChar()` on the `KeyEvent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#getUnicodeChar()), what do you get back? "When I press the ´ key and the o key, I shouldn't receive two events" -- why do you think this? After all, [the documentation for `getDeadChar()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyCharacterMap.html#getDeadChar(int,%20int)) would seem to disagree with you.

Comment: "When you call getUnicodeChar() on the KeyEvent, what do you get back?" I get a 0 (zero)

Comment: OK, you're right :) I have just tested and the ´ key doesn't fire the KeyPress event. It fires only when the "o" is pressed afterwards. But with the getUnicodeChar you mention I get a 111 instead of 243 (the Unicode for the "ó")

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do? It is probably too low level.
A key down might not necessarily have anything to do with the final input text produced. For instance to produce on Japanese character one has to press a sequence of several keys.