# handle DispatchKeyEvent in Xamarin Forms Android platform when no control has the focus

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a Xamarin Forms project (.NET Standard 2.1) and I need to handle DispatchKeyEvent in the Android platform.  I have that working great if an Entry control has the focus but I need it to work when no control has the focus.

Based on [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44489238/dispatchkeyevent-not-firing-on-my-view) I have tried to give the Page that inherits from PageRenderer the focus.  (I realize that that post is not about a Xamarin Forms project.)

So I put the following in the PageRenderer in the Android project.

```
// in the PageRenderer class
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Page> e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged(e);
    if (e.OldElement != null || Element == null)
    {           return;       }
    try
    {
        this.Focusable = true;
        this.FocusableInTouchMode = true;
        bool f = IsFocused;  // this is false here
    } 
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(@"ERROR: ", ex.Message);
    }
}
```

But IsFocused is always false.

NOTE: the device ( a barcode scanner) has a hardware keyboard, which is what I am using in this case.

How can I get the code to hit the DispatchKeyEvent handler when no control has the focus?

Comment: *"I have tried to give the Page that inherits from PageRenderer the focus."* - You don't show any code that sets focus to the page. The code you show should make if **possible** to focus the page. Now you need code to call `Focus()` on the page. Not sure where you should add that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @ToolmakerSteve 's guidance I added this.RequestFocus() to the OnElementChanged block, and now my DispatchKeyEvent event handler gets hit even if there is no Entry control on the page.

```
this.Focusable = true;
this.FocusableInTouchMode = true;
this.RequestFocus();
bool f = IsFocused;  // now this is true because of RequestFocus()
```